# Ajax ModalPopupExtender postback doesn't work for one of the button

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have an AJAX ModalPopupExtender and the are two buttons inside it. Both buttons were causing postback very well, but suddenly one of the button stopped working on deployed version of my application and do no more postback calls. I have tried removing OkControlID, CancelControlID and defining validation group and also setting causesvalidation property.
It works fine on my local machine but it doesn't work after deploying on to the server. I have also tried to change the ajaxcontroltoolkit reference to newer version but still no luck.

```
<ajax:ModalPopupExtender ID="MyModalPopupExtender" runat="server" PopupControlID="MyLetterPopup" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="DummyBtn" CancelControlID="CloseGrid" />
<asp:Panel CssClass="textfont" ID="MyLetterPopup" runat="server" Style="display: none;
background-color: White; height: 500px; width: 1000px; padding-bottom: 1px;" ScrollBars="Vertical">
<fieldset style="background-color: White; border-color: #0077C3; border-width: 2px">
<legend class="legendfont" style="text-align: center">DEMO</legend>
<table style="width: 100%">
<tr>
     <td style="width: 93%" align="right">
     <asp:Button ID="PrintBtn" runat="server" Text="Print" CssClass="buttonnormal" OnClick="PrintBtn_Click" />
     </td>
     <td align="right">
     <asp:Button ID="EmailBtn" runat="server" Text="Email" CssClass="buttonnormal" OnClick="EmailBtn_Click"/>
     </td>
     <td align="right">
     <asp:Button ID="CloseGrid" runat="server" Text="Close" CssClass="buttonnormal" />
     </td>
 </tr>
 </table>                                                               //..some grids to show data
```

Comment: show some code what you tried

Comment: what is error showing in FireBug ???

Comment: Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500                                      I added the script that i found in a solution but that too didn.t work.

Comment: @samsam123 T too face the same problem, your button is firing and also postback too but there is script error. It would be useful if you post full code

Comment: finally resolved it..it was happening because i installed vs2013 lately on my machine and my website was built on vs2010. somehow that was creating a problem.it worked fine when done from 2010 only machine